# Nextjs 12 - I receive wrong query param in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, server, next.js

On server

```
server.get('/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/:slug', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.params', req.params) // {slug: "vtv1"}
    return app.render(req, res, '/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/[slug]', req.params)
  })
```

In _app.js getInitialProps

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  console.log('MyApp query', ctx.query) // => {slug: [slug]} -> why?
 
  ...
  return { }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm using nextjs 12.2.5
Thanks

Another case.
On server

```
server.get('/:slug.html', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.params', req.params) // {slug: "dong-cung"} ok! -> because url is "/dong-cung.html"
    return app.render(req, res, `/[slug].html`, req.params)
  })
```

In _app.js

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const usingSSR = EXPORT_SSR === 'true'
  console.log('MyApp query', ctx.query) //{slug: "dong-cung"} -> I am confusing with above case "/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/[slug]"
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You wrote:

```
'/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/[slug]'
```

While you may want
```
`/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/${req.params.slug}`
``` no?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, should I render like this?
```app.render(req, res, '/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/${req.params.slug}', req.params)```

Comment: You need to replace single quotes "'" with back quotes "`" to use javascript literals

Comment: I had just added another case. Is there different here? Please explain to me. Many thanks!